# Function not implemented macro?

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm trying to create a macro so I can specify that a function is not implemented yet (and will crash the program when invoked). Here's what I came up with:

```
#define NIMPL crash(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ " not implemented yet")
```

And you'd use it like so:

```
void myFunction() {
    NIMPL;
}
```

However, this usage causes this error:

```
../feta/include/feta.h:19:41: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
 #define NIMPL crash(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ " not implemented yet")
                                         ^
```

`crash()` is a function that accepts one string as a parameter, prints out the message, and calls `exit(1)`.

I can confirm that `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` alone, without the concatenation works fine. Also, concatenating two strings without `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` works fine: `"<stuff>""<other stuff>"`. But doing both at the same time does not work.

I've tried using the [stringizing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x.aspx), but it did not work (if it even exists in GCC).

Comment: For C, you might as well use `__func__`, which unlike `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is standard. `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` differs from `__func__` only for C++. (This doesn't solve your problem.)

Comment: arent you just missing ## between the 2 strings

Comment: @pm100: `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is treated as the name of a `char[]` object, not a macro, so `##` isn't going to help.

Comment: @pm100 `error: pasting "__PRETTY_FUNCTION__" and "" not implemented yet"" does not give a valid preprocessing token`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard C and C++ provide the "magic identifier" `__func__`, which acts as if it were the name of a static `char` array containing the name of the current function. (Actually the value is implementation-defined in C++.)

gcc, as an extension, provides `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, which is identical to `__func__` for C, and provides some additional information for C++.

That doesn't solve the problem you're asking about, which is that string literal concatenation applies only to string literals.

You say your `crash()` function takes a single string as an argument.

I suggest either modifying `crash()` so it takes two arguments, or writing a new wrapper function that takes two arguments. You can then use:

```
#define NIMPL crash(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, " not implemented yet")
```

(Since you're using C++ you can overload it with the same name.) Concatenating the two strings is left as an exercise.

You could also add a second string argument to your existing `crash()` function and give it a default value of `""` to avoid breaking existing calls.

Answer (score 2):

In C (as the question was originally tagged), `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is another name for `__func__`, which is not a string literal. In C++, it is decorated with the function signature, but it is still not a string literal.

From the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) (especially note the last sentence):

> The identifier `__func__` is implicitly declared by the translator as if, immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
> ```
> static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> appeared, where function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing function. This name is the unadorned name of the function. As an extension, at file (or, in C++, namespace scope), `__func__` evaluates to the empty string.
> ...
> In C, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is yet another name for `__func__`, except that at file (or, in C++, namespace scope), it evaluates to the string `"top level"`. In addition, in C++, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` contains the signature of the function as well as its bare name.
> ...
> These identifiers are variables, not preprocessor macros, and may not be used to initialize `char` arrays or be concatenated with string literals.

Since you are using C++, you may consider defining `crash` as a variadic template function rather than a macro, to provide some more flexibility.

```
void crash_t (std::ostringstream &oss)
{
    oss << std::endl;
    write(2, &oss.str()[0], oss.str().size());
    exit(1);
}

template <typename A, typename... REST>
void crash_t (std::ostringstream &oss, A arg, REST... rest)
{
    oss << arg;
    crash_t(oss, rest...);
}

template <typename... ARGS>
void crash (ARGS... args)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    crash_t(oss, args...);
}
```

Comment: I believe `__FUNCTION__` and `__func__` are the same, both print "myFunction", but `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` prints "void myFunction()".

Comment: @ChrisSmith: If `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` gives you `"void myFunction()"`, then you're compiling C++, not C. Please make sure the tags on your question match the language you're using.

Comment: Then you are compiling as C++.