# Plain C equivalent to Rust's unimplemented!() macros

Tags: c, gcc, llvm-gcc, c17, c23

**Please note that this is not a question on C++, but on plain C**

In Rust there is a handy macro `unimplemented!()` to let the runtime crash, to be used when a function is unimplemented.

I basically have resorted to `assert (false)` to emulate it in my C coding. Which doesn't work for release builds.

What I like about `assert(false)` over `exit(-1)` is that I end up in the debugger at the right spot.

I found [Function not implemented macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350814/function-not-implemented-macro) which looks good but the `crash` macro is not defined at least in my clang-gcc setup.

Comment: You could look to see what assert does and do the same thing even in non debug builds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the `abort()` function can be used for:

Ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/abort

Comment: Relying on UB is dangerous. Your code may be optimized in unusual ways rather than resulting in a crash.

Comment: Sure, it's better to use the portable version that sorts out whatever works on the particular environment. The UB thing was mostly for fun.

Comment: UB fun for now, but definitely not fun later on.

Comment: Example of what @WeijunZhou means, and counterexample to your "probably": https://godbolt.org/z/cbdq9re1s

Comment: `abort()` is probably even worse than `exit(-1)`, because for some reason results in `SIGSEGV` and not `SIGABRT` on Linux. Did we get a segfault because of bugs or because of `abort()`? These old, smelly signal handling functions are all best to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

"Magic number 139: SIGSEGV" is not very helpful... it essentially just means "oops your program crashed, here be bugs". So stay clear of `abort()` and `signal.h`.

Instead I'd cook together a custom macro, which you can then include in a header file etc.

For example:

```c
#define STR_(s) #s
#define STR(s) STR_(s)

#define HCF(msg)                           \
    do {                                   \
        printf("Halt and catch fire! ");   \
        puts(msg);                         \
        printf("Function: ");              \
        puts(__func__);                    \
        puts("File: " __FILE__);           \
        puts("Line: " STR(__LINE__));      \
        assert(0);                         \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                \
    }while(0)
```

Example output:

```
Halt and catch fire! Unimplemented function executed!
Function: some_unimplemented_function
File: /app/example.c
Line: 20
```

The `assert(0)` is only there in case you want to end up with the debugger there in debug build.